# d3 marker is not displayed

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, marker

I have created a force directed graph using http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278 example. I have appended the markers to the paths:

```
var svg = d3.select("#entitiesGraph").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
.data(["end"])
.enter().append("svg:marker")
.attr("id", "end")
.attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
.attr("refX", 15)
.attr("refY", -1.5)
.attr("markerWidth", 12)
.attr("markerHeight", 12)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("svg:path")
.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

Everything works fine except the markers - they are not displayed, however in  javascript console I can see that they are appended to the svg container.

Has someone an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Why do you think they are not displayed? http://jsfiddle.net/3ydk4Lwy/

Comment: I tried your example and it is working. However not in my code and that is strange. The graph visualization which I am creating is part of one bigger project, we are using many libraries, I am afraid that there could be some dependency conflict. But I have no idea how to find it out...

Comment: What is the size of node circles in  your app?

Comment: Are you using a `<base>` html tag in your app?

Comment: The radius of node circles is varying from 5 to 30. And no, I am not using <base> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if you have solved this challenge now. I faced a similar problem. My approach in the context of your question is:

```
var svg = d3.select("#entitiesGraph").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
.data(["end"])
.enter().append("svg:marker")
.attr("id", window.location.href + "/end") // not .attr("id", "end")
.attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
.attr("refX", 15)
.attr("refY", -1.5)
.attr("markerWidth", 12)
.attr("markerHeight", 12)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("svg:path")
.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("marker-end", "url(#" + window.location.href + "/end)"); // not .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

I *think* this is because your code is looking for the element with 'end' id under "www.yourdomain/" whereas you want it to look under "www.yourdomain/partofyourwebsite/pageGraphIsRenderedIn" although I am not certain this is correct.

Comment: Hi, yes, the problem was really due to a wrong URL ;)